# front end drag and drop + SVG + backend ajax calls

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, svg, raphael

I am currently doing some research into the following:

I have a relational database with a table that contains circles. To keep it simple, let us assume that all circles have the same radius and each circle has an x and y position. I have some ORM plus server side technology that spews out SVG of all circles.

Users should be able to drag and drop additional circles onto the SVG ‘canvas’ that depicts the latest state of the circles database table. I am not too sure about the drag and drop functionality. I would prefer the drag and drop events to update the database rather than the client side SVG (i.e. drag and drop issue ajax calls to the backend). Angular JS (or jquery or whatever) would take care of synching backend and the frontend’s SVG.

Any pointers regarding relevant front end technology and/or examples would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A common approach is to make use of the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library to handle drag/drop. It provides the UI interaction, and drap / drop events for start / end drag processing. An AJAX call on the drop event can take care of the sync. ( see `draggable` and `droppable` )

Comment: I have read bad things about jquery ui. What does everyone else think?

Comment: I also seem to get many close request. Could whoever requests this question to be closed at least tell me why. Thanks.

Comment: Raphael handles drag and drop better than any UI library out there. Why not stick to its handlers? As for syncing, take a look at http://meteor.com/ if you want something big, or http://sharejs.org/ if you want something small. They both should do the job pretty well.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had a look at raphael drag and drop feature this morning. Usually this is used to directly manipulate the front end's svg. I guess I could use the handlers to update the backend and then refresh the svg generated by the backend. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: Right, you can invoke sync function from those drag and drop callbacks. If you want to just track final positions, do the sync on drop. If you want to track the movement, sync also on move, but make sure to debounce it.

Comment: @Hubert OG please post as answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raphael handles drag and drop better than any UI library out there. Why not stick to its handlers? As for syncing, take a look at http://meteor.com if you want something big, or http://sharejs.org if you want something small. They both should do the job pretty well

You can invoke sync function from those drag and drop callbacks. If you want to just track final positions, do the sync on drop. If you want to track the movement, sync also on move, but make sure to debounce it (using Sugar.js, or build-in Underscore).